# Impact of the "_id" field in elasticsearch, in the search method?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have some trouble with elasticsearch... I managed to create a reproducible example on my machine, the code is at the end of the post.

I just create 6 users, `"Roger Sand"`, `"Roger Gilbert"`, `"Cindy Sand"`, `"Cindy Gilbert"`, `"Jean-Roger Sands"`, `"Sand Roger"`, and index it by its names.

Then I run a query to match "Roger Sand", and display the associated score.

Here is the executions of the same script, with 2 set of differents ids : 84046 to 84051 and 84047 to 84052 (just shifted by 1).

The results are not in the same order, and have not the same score :

**Execution with 84046...84051**

```
Sand Roger => 0.8838835
Roger Sand => 0.2712221
Cindy Sand => 0.22097087
Jean-Roger Sands => 0.17677669
Roger Gilbert => 0.028130025
```

**Execution with 84047..84052**

```
Roger Sand => 0.2712221
Sand Roger => 0.2712221
Cindy Sand => 0.22097087
Jean-Roger Sands => 0.17677669
Roger Gilbert => 0.15891947
```

My question is **Why the "id" have an impact on a search through "full_name" ?**

Here is a complete ruby code of the reproductible script.

```
first_id = 84046 # Or 84047
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(:log => true)
client.transport.reload_connections!
client.indices.delete({:index => 'test'})
client.indices.create({ :index => 'test' })
client.perform_request('POST', 'test/_refresh')

["Roger Sand", "Roger Gilbert", "Cindy Sand", "Cindy Gilbert", "Jean-Roger Sands", "Sand  Roger" ].each_with_index do |name, i|
  i2 = first_id + i
  client.create({
    :index => 'test', :type => 'user',
    :id => i2,
    :body => { :full_name => name }
  })
end

query_options = {
  :type => 'user', :index => 'test',
  :body => {
    :query => { :match => { :full_name => "Roger Sand" } } 
  }
}

client.perform_request('POST', 'test/_refresh')

client.search(query_options)["hits"]["hits"].each do |hit|
  $stderr.puts "#{hit["_source"]["full_name"]} => #{hit["_score"]}"
end
```

Here is a command line

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test' 
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test' 
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh' 
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84047?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Roger Sand"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84048?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Roger Gilbert"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84049?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Cindy Sand"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84050?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Cindy Gilbert"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84051?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Jean-Roger Sands"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84052?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Sand Roger"}'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh' 
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search?pretty' -d '{"query":{"match":{"full_name":"Roger Sand"}}}'


curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84046?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Roger Sand"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84047?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Roger Gilbert"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84048?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Cindy Sand"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84049?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Cindy Gilbert"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84050?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Jean-Roger Sands"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/84051?op_type=create' -d '{"full_name":"Sand Roger"}'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search?pretty' -d '{"query":{"match":{"full_name":"Roger Sand"}}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within the distributed score calculation.

You create a new index with default settings, that is, 5 shards. Each shard is its own Lucene index. When you index your data, Elasticsearch needs to decide to which shard the document should go and it does so by hashing on the _id (in absence of the routing parameter).

So, by shifting the IDs, you eventually distributed the documents to different shards. As written above, each shard is its own Lucene index and when you search across multiple shards, you have to combine the different scores of each separate shard and due to the different routing, the individual scores are different.

You can verify this by adding `explain` to your query. For `Sand Roger`, the idf is calculated as `idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1) = 0.30685282` and `idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=2) = 1` respectively, which yields the different results.

You can change either the shard size to 1 or the query type to a dfs type. Searching against `http://localhost:9200/test/user/_search?pretty&query_type=dfs_query_and_fetch` will give you correct scores, because of its

> initial scatter phase which goes and computes the distributed term frequencies for more accurate scoring

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#dfs-query-and-fetch

Answer (score 1):

The scoring will always wary with a small data set and the default Elasticsearch index settings of 5 shards.

Use an index with a single shard for a test like this, or use a much bigger data set, so the distribution of the corpus across shards is more balanced.